# Split sorted array into list with sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a sorted array of float32 Values, I want to split this array into a list of lists containing only the same Values like this:

```
>>> split_sorted(array) # [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3.]
>>> [[1., 1., 1.], [2., 2.], [3.]]
```

My current approach is this Function

```
def split_sorted(array):
    split = [[array[0]]]

    s_index = 0
    a_index = 1
    while a_index < len(array):
        while a_index < len(array) and array[a_index] == split[s_index][0]:
            split[s_index].append(array[a_index])
            a_index += 1
        else:
            if a_index < len(array):
                s_index += 1
                a_index += 1
                split.append([array[a_index]])
```

My Question now is, is there a more Pythonic way to do this? maybe even with numpy? And is this the most performant way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the typical length of the input array and number of unique elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

With `a` as the array, we can use `np.split` -

```
np.split(a,np.flatnonzero(a[:-1] != a[1:])+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: a
Out[16]: array([1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3.])

In [17]: np.split(a,np.flatnonzero(a[:-1] != a[1:])+1)
Out[17]: [array([1., 1., 1.]), array([2., 2.]), array([3.])]
```

**Approach #2**

Another more performant way would be to get the *splitting* indices and then slicing the array and `zipping` -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, a[:-1] != a[1:], True])
out = [a[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])]
```

**Approach #3**

If you have to get a list of sublists as output, we could re-create with list duplication -

```
mask = np.r_[True, a[:-1] != a[1:], True]
c = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(mask))
out = [[i]*j for i,j in zip(a[mask[:-1]],c)]
```

#### Benchmarking

Timings for vectorized approaches on `1000000` elements with `10000` unique elements -

```
In [145]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,10000,(1000000)))

In [146]: x = a

# Approach #1 from this post
In [147]: %timeit np.split(a,np.flatnonzero(a[:-1] != a[1:])+1)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop

# Approach #2 from this post
In [148]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, a[:-1] != a[1:], True])
     ...: out = [a[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.18 ms per loop

# Approach #3 from this post
In [197]: %%timeit
     ...: mask = np.r_[True, a[:-1] != a[1:], True]
     ...: c = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(mask))
     ...: out = [[i]*j for i,j in zip(a[mask[:-1]],c)]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop

# @RafaelC's soln
In [149]: %%timeit
     ...: v,c = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
     ...: out = [[a]*b for (a,b) in zip(v,c)]
10 loops, best of 3: 25.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Well, this is something I can work with :) But I'll wait for more answers before I set this Question as solved

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and `zip`

```
v,c = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
[[a]*b for (a,b) in zip(v,c)]
```

Outputs

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0]]
```

Timings for a 6,000,000 sized array

```
%timeit v,c = np.unique(x, return_counts=True); [[a]*b for (a,b) in zip(v,c)]
18.2 ms ± 236 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.split(x,np.flatnonzero(x[:-1] != x[1:])+1)
424 ms ± 11.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit [list(group) for value, group in itertools.groupby(x)]
180 ms ± 4.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Share the setup for `x` for the timings?

Comment: @Divakar Had simply `x = np.array([1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3.]*100000)`. Timing with `np.array([np.random.randint(50) for _ in range(1000000)])` yields similar results, but testing with sorted `np.array(sorted([np.random.randint(50) for _ in range(1000000)]))` your solutions rises to be faster :)

Comment: Well the first two setups are wrong as OP mentioned the inputs are sorted ones and my approaches are specifically leveraging it for performance. Also, whenever you are posting a speedup comparison, please list the setup used. Without the setup, nobody can reproduce it.

Comment: Yep, my solution is my generic and have to consider that there is no necessity for the extra time for the sorting. Forgot to include the setups ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) has this exact behavior.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(group) for value, group in groupby(array)]
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3.]
>>> for k, g in groupby(a) :
...     print k, list(g)
... 
1.0 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
2.0 [2.0, 2.0]
3.0 [3.0]
```

You may join the lists, if you like:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for k, g in groupby(a) :
...     result.append( list(g) )
... 
>>> result
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved your code a bit, it's not pythonic, but doesn't use external libraries (and also your code didn't work on the last element in the array):

```
def split_sorted(array):
    splitted = [[]]
    standard = array[0]
    li = 0 # inner lists index
    n = len(array)

for i in range(n):
    if standard != array[i]:
        standard = array[i]
        splitted.append([]) # appending empty list
        li += 1
    split[li].append(array[i])
return splitted


# test
array = [1,2,2,2,3]
a = split_sorted(array)
print(a)enter code here
```