# Function to print all the sequence in ascending order in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to take all the ascending order sequence from a list and print the sublist. How should I match the elements of the list?

I have tried iterating over the list and compare the elements but not working the way I want it to work.

```
def ascending_order_sequence(list1):
    sublist = []

    for i in range(len(no_list)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(no_list) + 1):
```

Dont know how to compare and then fetch the sublists

TEST CASE 1: `[4,5,9,7,1,4,3,8,10]`
OUTPUT: `[4,5,9] [1,4] [3,8,10]`

TEST CASE 2: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
OUTPUT : `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

TEST CASE 3: `[8,6,2,1,0]`
OUTPUT: `[]`

Comment: Related question (not the same but could give a hint to the solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571422/split-sorted-array-into-list-with-sublists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(d):
    res =[]
    tmp =[]
    val =d[0]
    for i in range(1,len(d)):
        if d[i]>=val:
            tmp.append(val)
            val =d[i]
        else:
            tmp.append(val)
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp =[]
            val = d[i]
    tmp.append(val)
    res.append(tmp)
    return res




l = [4,5,9,7,1,4,3,8,10,1]

print(func(l))
```

output

```
 [[4, 5, 9], [7], [1, 4], [3, 8, 10], [1]]
```

Comment: Why is 7 in there? Where is 10?

Comment: how to get the last element? in the particular case the element '10'?

Comment: @MarkMeyer , as per Op problem it is increase sequence problem, where in sequence element must be greater or eqal to previous one, since for 7 new seqence started and condition not followed it is there as single lement

Comment: @PrithviSingh solution updated

Comment: Make  a condition when appending to mai. List that length should be more than 2